# ES6 class method not present in instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am updating my old node.js project to include ES6 features in order to eventually migrate to typescript, but I can't get this class to work. I have defined a class in a separate file:

```
class Database {

constructor(connectionPool) {
    this._connectionPool = connectionPool;
}

_getConnection () {
    console.log("getting connection");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._connectionPool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                console.log("connection rejected");
            } else {
                console.log("connection resolved");
                resolve(connection);
            }
        });
    });
}
}
module.exports = Database;
```

I am then importing this class into another file and trying to create a Database instance:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const Database = require('./database');

module.exports = databaseInitializer;

function databaseInitializer(config) {

    const pool = mysql.createPool(config);
    const db = new Database(pool);
    console.log(Database.toString());
    console.log(db.__proto__);
    return db;
}
```

Finally, i am using above function to get the database instance:

```
const database = require('./models/databaseInitializer')(mysqlConfig);
console.log(database);
```

Now, my database instance has a `_connectionPool` property, but no prototype and more importantly, no `_getConnection` property.
What am I missing?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: What do you mean by "*it has no prototype*"? Surely `db.__proto__` is not `null`. Btw, don't use the deprecated `__proto__` getter, use `Object.getPrototypeOf(db)`.

Comment: `class` methods are not enumerable. Probably node's `console.log` doesn't print them because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_getConnection` property belongs to the prototype of `database` and **hence this property is the non-enumerable property of `database`**.

You can access this property by doing

```
console.log(database._getConnection) //should show the function
```

Comment: you are right, thanks, my problem was stemming from something else